# Resizing and displaying image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to resize an image and then display it to check whether it has been resized or not.

```
#include"cv.h"
#include"highgui.h"
#include<iostream>
 using namespace cv;

 int main()
 {
     IplImage* ipl = cvLoadImage("test1.jpg");
     cvShowImage("original:",ipl);
     CvSize size = cvSize(128,128); 
    IplImage* tmpsize=cvCreateImage(size,8,0);   
    cvResize(ipl,tmpsize,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    cvShowImage("new",tmpsize);

     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
 }
```

But it produces an error 
OpenCV Error:Assertion failed==dst.type<>> in unknown function 
file c:\slave\winInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp
line 3210.
Please point what am i doing wrong and suggest some way to overcome it.
On the other hand other code works fine.

```
 IplImage *source = cvLoadImage( "test1.jpg");
// Here we retrieve a percentage value to a integer
int percent =50;
// declare a destination IplImage object with correct size, depth and channels
      IplImage *destination = cvCreateImage
( cvSize((int)((source->width*percent)/100) , (int)((source->height*percent)/100) ),
                                     source->depth, source->nChannels );

//use cvResize to resize source to a destination image
cvResize(source, destination);

// save image with a name supplied with a second argument
      cvShowImage("new:",destination);
      waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Please explain.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to store the result of the operation in an image that is not compatible with the original: both images must be of the same type (nchannels and depth).

Comment: @karlphillip-I understood that both images have some difference but i was not able to figure out the difference.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the first or the second code example?

If you're using the first one, I guess your "tmpsize" should have the same number of channels as your source file.

Comment: I have tried using both the codes.The 1st one produced an error but the 2nd one runs perfectly fine.And what do you mean by same number of channels?

Comment: As karlphillip explained "ipl" and "tmpsize" have to be the same type since cvResize requires you to meet this criteria. So make sure they both have the same depth and number of channels. For further information check out the OpenCV documentation: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage

Answer (score 0):

in the first example you write 0  for number of channels
so change
IplImage* tmpsize=cvCreateImage(size,8,0); 
line 
IplImage* tmpsize=cvCreateImage(size,ipl->depth, ipl->nChannels );